# How to create a bootstrap style InputField?

Tags: gui-construction, inputfield

I am trying to create a bootstrap style InputField in Mathematica. Here is what I've done so far:

```
Framed[
    InputField[Dynamic[text], String, Appearance -> "Frameless"], 
    FrameStyle -> LightGray, 
    RoundingRadius -> 5
]
```

However, since the Appearance is set to Frameless, the InputField loses the ability to show the focus (a slightly thick border usually of light blue color) when the text insertion point is inside the InputField.

[image: InputField with focus example]

One way to bring back the focus feature would be to use an EventHandler that dynamically changes the FrameStyle when the insertion pointer is inside the InputField. But I cannot think of a way to specify this in the EventHandler. Is there a way to specify this or is there a better way to do this?